# How to sort list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I have a nested list

```
a=[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x1,y2],[x2,y1],[x7,y7],[x1,y3]]
```

I want to sort it as:

```
a=[[x1,y1],[x1,y2],[x1,y3],[x2,y1],[x2,y2],[x7,y7]]
```

I tried to use lambda function but it wouldn't compile:

```
a=sorted(a,lambda x,y:x==y?x[0]+x[1],x[0])
```

How do I use `sorted` to get my desired output?

Comment: Could you show an actual, runnable example, and explain in what way the default sort doesn't do what you need?

Comment: I wanted to see if we could use the lambda function for the above question

Comment: @learner: Since the syntax is not correct, we are only *guessing* as to what you want. You need to be more explicit in how you want the sort to behave.

Answer (score 1):

You could use actual Python syntax, such as a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0] + x[1] if x == y else x[0])
```

This is based on a interpreting your `?` syntax as the Javascript conditional expression syntax.

This of course assumes there is a separate `y` variable defined somewhere:

```
>>> a = [[1,1], [2,2], [1,2], [2,1], [7,7], [1,3]]
>>> y = [1, 1]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0] + x[1] if x == y else x[0])
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1], [7, 7]]
```

Comment: I get an error with this Martjin--looks like a missing a positional parameter to the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `sorted(a)` will give what you want, right out-of-the box:

```
>>> a = [[1,1], [2,2], [1,2], [2,1], [7,7], [1,3]]
>>> sorted(a)
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [7, 7]]
```